# Django generateschema ignores URLs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn to create a Backend with Django, together with an Angular frontend.
In order to make the api a little more consistent I tried to create a API schema to use the OpenAPI Generator.

I have run the command `./manage.py generateschema --file schema.yml`. But: The yml file does not have any information about the `users.url`. I have added the `get_schema_view` from the rest_framework, with the same result.

The (main) app urls.py looks like this:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/users/', include('users.urls'), name="users"),
    path('api/network/', include('networkController.urls'), name="network"),
    path('api/files/', include('fileController.urls'), name="files"),
    path('api/', get_schema_view(
        title="API Documentation",
        description="API for all things"
    ), name='openapi-schema')
]
```

The networkController.urls looks like this:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.startNetwork)
]
```

which is found by the schema generator.

The users.urls looks like this:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login),
    path('register/', views.registerUser)
]
```

I have tried to move all urls to the (main) backend.urls and include the views directly, I have tried "layering" them all.

```py
# backend.urls:
path('api/', include('api.urls'))
```

```py
# api.urls:
path('users/', include('users.urls'))
```

without any changes.

I tried looking up, why - but without success. If I run the server and make a GET-Request via curl to localhost:8000/api/users/login directly, it works perfectly fine.

Could you please help me figure out, what I did wrong or guide me to a tutorial, which would cover the topic a little more detailled? 
(And yes. Maybe I should just switch to something like FastAPI, but I really love Djangos Auth.Users and the easy constant, connection to a database)

Thanks in advance!

(EDIT: You can find the whole code in my [GitHub](https://github.com/Ichor1d/networks))

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out why my code didn't work. I use Class Based Views but I think this will also work for Method Based ones.

It looks like `generateschema` does not like uppercase method names:

```
class ...(UpdateAPIView):


    serializer_class = ...
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['PUT']
    
    ...
```

Instead of `['PUT']` I used `['put']`

```
class ...(UpdateAPIView):


    serializer_class = ...
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['put']
    
    ...
```

So, replace all the uppercase letters with lowercase letters.